# Help me find this manga i lost

Tags: super-hxeros

It's a colored webcomic not sure if it was in webtoon.

MC is an orange haired boy who for some circumstances ends up working and living with a group of super heros

OH yes and I think there was a scene where he was wearing a wig and they thought he was a girl... I think his sister forced him to wear it and go get something from the vanding machine

Thats vaguely all I remember it's been a loooong time